# Excel VBA reference to other workbook through "set" with generic variables, keeping that reference in formulas

Tags: vba, excel

Here's my problem. I'm running a central KPI file that has to be updated each week. It is refering to files that have a specific name + the current week that they're in. For example, the KPI refers to a DT1P and MPO file, both ending with the current week.

So, for week 2016-28, the central KPI file should look up the values in MPO2016-28.xlsx and DT1P2016-28.xlsx.

For week 2016-29, the central KPI file should look up the values in MPO2016-29.xlsx and DT1P2016-29.xlsx.

However, when I try to run formulas to do some calculations from those sheets, I have no clue how I can make the week generic (the week is being made in `Range("E1")` in the KPI file), without just refering to the entire location the file is. How can I solve this?

I have:

```
Set wb_MPO = Workbooks.Open("\\S007v\MPO" & Range("e1").Value & ".xlsx")
wb_KPI.Activate
Set wb_DT1P = Workbooks.Open("\\S007v\DT1P" & Range("e1").Value & ".xlsx")
wb_KPI.Activate
```

To define the files that need to be opened.

However, my formulas look like this (there's many more of them, but the principle stays the same, so I won't bother you with them)

```
   Range("E4").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX('[MPO2016-28.xlsx]CSR MPO'!C10,MATCH(RC[-4],'[MPO2016-28.xlsx]CSR MPO'!C1,0),0)"
```

Could it be something like:

```
   Range("E4").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=INDEX('[wb_MPO]CSR MPO'!C10,MATCH(RC[-4],'[wb_MPO]CSR MPO'!C1,0),0)"
```

Or am I totally off?

Thanks in advance for your support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but it would be:

```
Range("E4").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=INDEX('[" & wb_MPO.Name & "]CSR MPO'!C10,MATCH(RC[-4],'[" & wb_MPO.Name & "]CSR MPO'!C1,0),0)"
```

This will only work if the workbook you are trying to reference is open though. I feel like there are probably better ways to extract this information than opening the workbook and writing a formula to a cell.

Comment: Hi Kyle, Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the code  `"& wb_MPO.name & "` does not seem to work. 
The files themselves have been opened in the background, that's why I'm using the `"set wb_MPO= Workbooks.open"` formula.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or what seems to not be working?

Comment: Hi Kyle, nothing short of genious, thanks a lot :)!!!!
Could you explain to me though what that `.name` part of the function actually does?

Comment: When you set the variable `wb_MPO`, it is holding a workbook object. Each object has properties (information you can set or retrieve) and methods (things the object can do, or you can do to the object). `.Name` is a property of the workbook object that gives you the name and extension of the workbook.